# MacOS Monterey can't share screen on meeting call services

Tags: mac, google-chrome, zoom

Since upgrading to MacOS Monterey, I cannot share my screen on any of the common call service applications:  Google Meet, Zoom or Microsoft Teams.  I get an error with prompt to update my Privacy permissions.

However, all of these applications are added and checked in Screen Recording tab of Security & Privacy settings.

[image: Security & Privacy settings]

Other posts on this site seem to identify this as a problem with Chrome, but since i have same issue using Google Meet in Safari and with stand-alone apps (Zoom, Teams), I think it's a problem with Monterey. I shared my screen often with previous versions of MacOS.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post a pic of the "error with prompt"

Comment: Have you tried removing the apps from **Privacy** > **Screen Recording**, then re-adding them? (Maybe even restart before re-adding)

Comment: Note that you have to restart those apps for changes to take effect, so restarting your Mac (as @agarza suggests) would probably help.